# Meaning of this kanji compound: 入植用合成戦術個体

Tags: kanji

This kanji compound is from a video game, and I'm having problems understanding it... the entire sentence for context is: "―入植用合成戦術個体― の覚醒を確認。これより性能試験を開始する."

I understand everything except for that monster compound! I've researched the kanji separately and can only come up with fragmented meanings which don't make much sense together: "Used by settlers", "synthetic", "tactics", "individual". I feel like I may have mistaken some of the separate kanji meanings because this isn't making sense to me, anyone have any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely a made-up phrase used only in this video game. And I think you are already parsing it right.

個体 ("individual") is the main noun of the phrase. It's an individual as opposed to a group or species, and it refers to *one* monster, robot or something like that, depending on the context.

And the following three words each modify 個体.

- 入植用: used for plantation, colonial
- 合成: synthetic/synthesized, composite; as in [synthetic rubber](http://Synthetic_rubber)
- 戦術: tactic/tactical; as in [tactical nuclear weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_nuclear_weapon)

I don't know how each of these modifiers is really important to the plot of the game. If it still doesn't make sense, perhaps you don't have to worry much. Just take it as some random name of a weapon/robot/etc which just seems difficult.